# How to read realtime data of sensors from firebase to flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mobile

How do you read the sensor from the database which is the image below to the flutter? it seems there is no updated or lastest version for flutter realtime database video in the internet. we also keep debugging it but it is not showing any changes.

Firebase image:

[image: Sensors from the firebase]

Source code:
The problem we mostly getting at is at the fetchHumidityReadings because we tried to make it into smaller problems were it shows that value '68' in the mobile application but the fetchHumidityReadings is not overwriting it or replace the value.

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types, use_build_context_synchronously, unnecessary_null_comparison

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class homePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const homePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<homePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<homePage> {
  List<double> humidityReadings = [];
  String humidity = '68';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchHumidityReadings();
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('fetchHumidityReadings() executed');
    }
  }

  void fetchHumidityReadings() {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Inside fetchHumidityReadings()');
    }
    DatabaseReference databaseReference =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Sensor').child('Humidity');
    databaseReference.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value;
      if (data != null) {
        // `data` has fetched a value
        // You can use `data` here
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Fetched data: $data');
        }
        setState(() {
          humidity = data.toString();
        });
      } else {
        // `data` is null, indicating that it did not fetch a value
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('No data fetched');
        }
        setState(() {
          humidity = '69'; // Set humidity to an appropriate default value
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          "LetsGrow",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(12, 192, 223, 1.0),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shadowColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 95, 94, 94),
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffeeeeee),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                'Sensor Readings',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35,
                  fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Humidity: $humidity',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35,
                  fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you `print('$data')`, what does it output?

Comment: It does not output anything sir

Comment: We already tried to debug it because it does not output anything.

Comment: That seems unlikely. Any `print` statement should print something, even if it is `null`.

Comment: Yeah we really do not why it is not showing any print even when we tried to debug it using "inside fetchHumidityReadings". The debugger will show that it made it inside but after that kdebug it will not collect any information from the database did we do something wrong?